# Content Type not available as dropdown in newform.aspx

Tags: content-type

I've added a couple of CT's to a list. I can create a item with a selected CT from the ribbon. However when I select new item from the link (located in the page) it always gives me the default CT.

I have seen this where the newform has a dropdown allowing the user to select the required CT. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the list item template (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.ascx) you will find that the `ChangeContentType` control is used.

You need to create your own control, inherit it from `ChangeContentType` control and override visible property. After this you should create your own template and use it for your list.

```
public override bool Visible
{
  [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)] get
  {
    if ((this.ControlMode == SPControlMode.Display) || this.List == null || (!this.List.ContentTypesEnabled || !base.Visible))
      return false;
    int num = 0;
    foreach (SPContentType spContentType in (IEnumerable<SPContentType>) this.ItemContext.ContentTypes)
    {
      if (this.ItemContext.FormContext.IsFolder || !spContentType.Id.IsChildOf(SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder))
        ++num;
    }
    return num > 1;
  }
  [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)] set
  {
    base.Visible = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I had a suspicion it was server side code :) should the above code be added to a VS feature? if could you please tell me how to do that. Thanks

Comment: You need to create SharePoint farm solution, add a user control and inherit it from `ChangeContentType` class, override visible property, add a safe control entry. Then add to this solution controltemplates mapped folder and copy list template from the DefaultTemplates.ascx, change `ChangeContentType` control to your control. The last, add your content types to the solution and register your list template in these content types.